# What is the effect of performing a less-than comparison between a matrix (2D array) and a value in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, deeplearning4j

I don't understand why I got a matrix of `bool` values when setting a matrix < a value in Python

`a3` has 12 elements and 12*0.8=9.6. How can 9.6 elements remain? Where is my mistake?

My code:

```
import numpy as np

keep_prod = 0.8
a3 = np.random.rand(3,4)
print("a3-before",a3)
d3 = np.random.rand(a3.shape[0],a3.shape[1])<keep_prod    ##### attention!!!
print("d3",d3)
```

The output:

```
a3-before 
[[ 0.6016695   0.733025    0.38694513  0.17916196]
 [ 0.39412193  0.22803599  0.16931667  0.30190426]
 [ 0.8822327   0.64064634  0.40085393  0.72317028]]
d3 
[[False  True  True False]
 [ True False  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True]]
```

Comment: Operator `<` is a boolean comparison operator. Naturally, it produces boolean values. What did you expect?

Comment: The `d3` line creates a new random array with the same shape as `a3`, and then compares each element to `keep_prod`.  It's hard to tell what you intend by the `12*0.8` calculation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you expect `< 0.8` to keep 80% of the elements in the original array.

However, what really happens is that it performs that comparison *elementwise*, and returns an array of the same shape. In other words, `d3` contains `True` where the corresponding element of `a3` was more than or equal to `0.8`, and `False` elsewhere.